# Jquery slideshow with counter corresponding with current image

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, logic, setinterval

I'm working on a 'widget' - i guess that's what you'd call it.

Either-way, the aim is to have a monitor which has an slideshow embedded onto the screen, with a counter which is red when the corresponding image is displayed. Also, if a counter is clicked, the corresponding image should display and the relevant counter should turn red - the other counters must stay blue.

I have gotten as far as having the slideshow functionality, but the counter i have integrated is driving me nuts! The counter is suppose to turn red, by adding a class, when the counter is displaying the corresponding image; which it does. But when you click a certain counter, the others are suppose to have their class removed and the one which is clicked is suppose to turn red.

I hope i'm explaining things well, here's the **[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BfpD5/1/)** i've been working on.

**HTML**

```
<div class="current">
<span id="Img1"></span>
<span id="Img2"></span>
<span id="Img3"></span>
</div>

<div id="monitor">
<div class="slideshow">
<img id="First"src="http://dummyimage.com/400x260/000/fff.png&text=Image+01" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x260/000/fff.png&text=Image+02" />
<img src="http://dummyimage.com/400x260/000/fff.png&text=Image+03" />
</div>
<div class="stand">
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.slideshow {
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 550px;
    height: 300px;
    background-color: #000;
    border:10px solid black;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
}
.slideshow img {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
.current span{
    width:10px;
    height:10px;    
    display: inline-block;     
    background-color:blue
}
.current .red{
    background-color:red;    
}
.stand{
  width: 560px;
  height: 120px;
  background: url(http://i.imgur.com/pwzFcSZ.png) no-repeat;
  background-position:center;

}
```

**JQUERY/JAVASCRIPT**

```
var count = 1;
setInterval(function () {
    count = ($(".slideshow :nth-child(" + count + ")").fadeOut("slow").next().length == 0) ? 1 : count + 1;
    $(".slideshow :nth-child(" + count + ")").fadeIn("slow");
    $(".current :nth-child(" + count + ")").addClass("red")
        .delay(2000)
        .queue(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("red");
        $(this).dequeue();
    });
}, 2000);

$(".current span").click(function () {
    $(this).addClass("red");
    $(".slideshow :nth-child(" + count + ")").fadeOut();
    $(".slideshow #First").fadeIn();
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple one line addiiton to remove class:

```
$( ".current span" ).click(function() {
   /* remove red class  of others before applying red to active one*/
    $('.current .red').removeClass('red')
  /* adjust counter*/
   count= $(this).index()+1;

   $(this).addClass("red");   
   $(".slideshow :nth-child("+count+")").fadeOut();
   $(".slideshow #First").fadeIn();    
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/BfpD5/4/)**</kbd>

Comment: Thanks @charlietfl. The code in your answer was already in my fiddle but i forgot to update or fork the jsfiddle. The problem with the code is that If you click the first button when the second image is displayed the counter continues, and as a result there are two red buttons - the first and last.

Comment: OK...need to adjust count  `count= $(this).index()+1;` Try updated demo

Comment: Thanks but it still happens; two of the buttons are red at the same time when the first button is clicked with the second image is showing :(. Edit: The issue was that it should've been index - 1, see here http://jsfiddle.net/k36pK/

Comment: simply adjusts the counter so when queue activates again count is set to item that was clicked